# What's the best practice about dealing with corners on a fixed-height element?

Tags: css, cross-browser, rounded-corners

Here is my problem. I have to round corners on a

```
<a href=""></a>
```

but without using CSS3 properties because my code is supposed to be cross-browser compliant (IE6 and earlier, Safari 3 and earlier).

What I managed to do is :

```
<span>
  <a href="">My link</a>
</span>
```

Giving my **span** a background image (5px width) left align and my **a** a 150px width image, right aligned so that the content could be fluid.

I still have problems with the rendering under IE7 and I would like to know if there is another cleaner way to do this.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rendering problems you describe probably come from `span` being an inline element.

Try using a `div` or giving the `span` `display: block`. You should then be able to specify width and height exactly and uniformly across all browsers.

Comment: Was not the exact answer because it made another problem under IE6. I fixed it by using the !important statement for IE6 and now it's finaly ok. May CSS3 be understood very quickly !